# How to get images stored in a database and display them on a HTML page using Flask?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I tried it doing it this way but the image didn't appear on the HTML page
It is a flask app accessing "image" database which has images stored in it with unique ids
How do I get the image stored in the Database using flask and display the image on the html page which I am rendering

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import *
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from io import BytesIO
import base64
import image

#from sqlalchemy_imageattach.entity import Image, image_attachment


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "manoj"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'mysql://root@localhost/image'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db.init_app(app)
class Images(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "imgs"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer , primary_key = True , nullable=False)
    img = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("parallax.html")

@app.route('/upload' , methods = ['POST'])
def upload():
    img  =  request.files['img_file']
    newfile = Images(img = img.read())
    db.session.add(newfile)
    db.session.commit()
    return "File Uploaded : " + img.filename

@app.route('/download')
def download():
    img = Images.query.filter_by(id = 1).first()
    newimg =  BytesIO(img.img) 
    img = image(newimg)
    return render_template("image.html" , data = img)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this isnt the answer you're looking for, but storing the actual images on disk, and only retrieving the filename or location from the database also works.

flask can return this image very easily using

```
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('PATH', filename='YOURIMAGE.png'), code=301)
```

I guess you have a specific reason to store the images in a database, but maybe this will help you anyway. Note this doesnt return html with the image embedded, but the image only.

Comment: Thank you very much 
I have tried this but this didnt seem to be a good option so

Answer (score 0):

Key word: blob

Convert your image to base64 string blob, then you can store it in db as text field